# Using Django or JS to turn on camera and scan QR-code

Tags: javascript, html, django, qr-code

I am now working on a project that can scan QR-code which contains ID of a good. Is there any method that I can have my website to switch on iPhone camera for scanning? Please give me some information about this or link.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use some UI technology to access camera, because the part of the app your users are running is the frontend. So, you'll have to **use javascript** and totally **not django**.

There's the [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) API that browsers expose.

Have a look at [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia) on how to use that.